# How to compile and install new kernel in Chrubuntu with samsung exynos 5 (ARM coretex-A15)?

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, arm, bootloader

I have successfully installed Chrubuntu 13.04 (kernel version 3.4) on samsung Chromebook Exynos5 with ARM coretex-A15. And I also tried to update the kernel version to 3.9 by downloading new kernel, compiling and installing. However, with successful installation(all required kernel img files in /boot directory were generated), after rebooting it, the kernel is still old version 3.4.

I compiled the kernel in Chromebook without cross-compile and ran default gcc in Chrubuntu 13.04. Is there any thing I missed during compiling new kernel? As I heard, there's no "grub" in arm linux, is that a problem? If somebody can pin point the problem or provide the solution to update the kernel, pls help me.

Comment: Did you try `make install`?  Typically */bin/installkernel* is the system location; but I don't know about a *ChromeBook*.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in that Grub is not (yet) supported on the Chromebook.

Olof @ Google posted about the process on:
https://plus.google.com/109993695638569781190/posts/34PYU79eUqP

Alternatively, you can use a chain-loaded U-boot:
http://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/u-boot-porting-guide/using-nv-u-boot-on-the-samsung-arm-chromebook